# Programmatically distinguish exceptions

Tags: java, exception

The type of an exception is often enough to handle it properly (for example you try to open a file and get a `FileNotFoundException`). However there are cases where you might catch multiple exception of the same type. For example, an `IllegalArgumentException` that can be caused by more than one argument. The `IllegalArgumentException` does not add any additional methods (or public fields) to the `Throwable` interface (accoding to the online [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html)) which means that the only information that you can rely on are the nested exception (which may or may not exist) and the message (which is for human consumption).

I don't like the idea of extending `IllegalArgumentException` to add structured information to it, because other people would have to learn the new class. And I don't like the idea of littering projects with very specific exception classes.
Using the message field is also a bad idea because it's not meant for programmatic access.

I think `IllegalArgumentException` should have included details such as the class function and argument(s) in question. And in general custom exceptions should provide additional detail (other then just their type) for a more fine grained exception handling.

What are considered generally the best practices for designing exception classes, and handling exceptions of the same type?

Comment: you could use multiple try-catch blocks in order to ensure you get the right exception from the right piece of code

Comment: `try{ someFunction(arg1, arg2, arg3); }` what if i got IllegalArgumentException caused by one of the arguments? I only have one `try`

Comment: i see what you mean... maybe you just check args before and don't throw an exception?

Comment: true, but this is just one specific case. In general, you should be able to get information from the exception other than just its type.

Comment: If you run into an IAE, that's a programming error. So look into the stacktrace for the method and add checks for all parameters before handing them to the method that threw the exception.

Comment: @Anthony Do you meant to say; you want error_code; and you feel error_msg is not sufficient to handling ???

Comment: The error message is not "not sufficient", it's just not meant for processing. It's useful in logs for people trying to fix the problem. An error code or other information would certainly be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, I think it *is* ideal to have one class of exception per "type of action a caller might reasonably want to take".  Of course, for one's own custom exceptions there could be a boolean or enum field providing some extra disambiguation, rather than creating trivial subclasses.

In your specific case I'm not convinced that trying to handle the exception is a good idea.  `RuntimeException` and its subclasses usually represent coding issues, and the same is true of `IllegalArgumentException`.  If the argument is illegal it shouldn't be passed in in the first place.

If you're in a situation where you're not *sure* if an argument is valid (maybe it's user input, or maybe you don't know the specific object you're calling the method on) then a better approach would be to have some way of *checking* the validity of the argument before passing it.  Rather than say "do this" and catch the exception, ask "can I do this?" before calling.

Answer (score 1):

Exception classes should be designed so as to provide all that is needed when they are caught. Note that `try/catch` statements are actually a form of type switch, so in general it is cleaner to create additional exception classes rather than confuse program logic by nesting too many `if`'s within `catch` clauses.

It has to be said that catch clauses are not very convenient if you want to organize your error handling code in an object oriented fashion, so there are different trade offs to keep in mind.

Note that standard exception classes do have information available on what piece of code caused the exception, even though I would not advise you to base on it your error handling logic.

If the current exception was thrown in a catch clause for a different exception this should be available with the `getCause()` method, while the `getStackTrace()` should provide access to the stack of calls that were active when your exception was thrown.

Again I don't advise you to use this information except for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Its true that the predefined exception classes are very general. But if you want more specific details about the exceptions then you should go for **user defined exceptions**. you should create your own exception classes with any level of details!

**here is the pseudo code:**

```
public class TooManyArguments extends exception{
    public String toString(){
    return ("..whatever information you want to give for this exception..")'
    }
```

}

and whenever you encounter exceptional situation throw an instance of this class

```
throw new TooManyArguments();
```